# RecyclerView with sqlite db working in activity but not working in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am the beginner in android
I have found many answers of a similar question  but no answer unfortunately worked for me
I am using recylcerView using card view to show student data .I am taking Data from My sqlite db.
My code works fine in activity but because of navigation drawer i put it in a fragment and it is showing blank.
here is my activity and fragment code.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private PersonDBHelper dbHelper;
private MyCustomAdapter adapter;
private String filter = "";
TextView textView;
public static int navItemIndex = 0;
Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
FloatingActionButton button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.person_list);
   /* toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/
    mDrawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.empty_view);


    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    //populate recyclerview
    populaterecyclerView(filter);




    button=findViewById(R.id.fab_add);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goToAddUserActivity();
        }
    });
}

private void populaterecyclerView(String filter) {
    dbHelper = new PersonDBHelper(this);

    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(dbHelper.peopleList(filter), this, mRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void goToAddUserActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddRecordActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

this is working fine but for the fragment i did following changes

StudentListFragment()

```
ublic class StudentListFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private PersonDBHelper dbHelper;
private MyCustomAdapter adapter;
FloatingActionButton button;
private String filter = "";
View rootView;
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

public static StudentListFragment newInstance(){

    StudentListFragment studentListFragment = new StudentListFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    studentListFragment.setArguments(args);
    return studentListFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}




@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {




   rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_list,container,false);
     mRecyclerView=rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    dbHelper = new PersonDBHelper(getContext());
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(dbHelper.peopleList(filter), getContext(), mRecyclerView);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    button=rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_add);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goToAddUserActivity();
        }
    });
    return rootView;


}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(false);
    ensureList();

}




private void goToAddUserActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddRecordActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("StudentList");
}
public  void ensureList(){
    if (dbHelper != null) {
        return;
    }
    View root = getView();
    if (root == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Content view not yet created");

    }   }
```

}

i am calling this fragment in navigation drawer code is working but not displaying any data. If i put this fragment first in navigation drawer menu means when navigation drawer activity starts this fragment will get open.In such case it is displaying my cards(my data) but if i switch to other fragment and return back to this fragment it is showing blank

Answer (score 0):

In fragment, onCreateView() method, please inflate your root view and return it immediately, do not do anything else.

Implement your logic to onViewCreated(). something like this :

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_list,container,false);
    return rootView;
    }

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("StudentList");

   mRecyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    dbHelper = new PersonDBHelper(getContext());
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(dbHelper.peopleList(filter), getContext(), mRecyclerView);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    button=view.findViewById(R.id.fab_add);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            goToAddUserActivity();
        }
    });
}
```

could you please try this. And make sure you have items in the list.

Comment: thank you for the reply.I tried your solution but it still showing blank screen. it is showing data just once when i open app .once i go to the other fragment and return back  it shows blank screen